# Can particles と and か be used together? If so what is the implication?

Tags: particles, particle-と, particle-か

When connecting nouns, と means "and" and か means "or." Can I use them together?

Ex.

> ツナか牛肉とチーズでサンドイッチを作る。

I think this would mean "I make a sandwich with tuna or beef and cheese."  If this is the case, how does the logic follow?  Is it a sandwich with 'tuna' **or** 'beef and cheese,' or is it a sandwich with 'tuna or beef' **and** cheese?

My first question on stackexchange Japanese, please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: If only natural languages were like C. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Native speaker here, but I cannot even tell if you are making one kind of sandwich or two kinds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context, it is obvious though, cheese is typed as チーズ in katakana.

> ツナか牛肉とチズでサンドイッチを作る。

Say, now we know we are preparing sandwiches. If we have "tuna", "cuts of beef" and "slices of cheese". In this case, it is normal to think to prepare sandwiches with the combination of “beef or tuna” and “cheese”. Whereas now we are seeing a can of “tuna in a water” and a can of “beef mixed with cheese sauce” at the supermarket, you might think it as preparing sandwiches with “tuna” or “beef and cheese”.

Edit: The comment is too small to see what it is.

Yes, it's context dependent. Say, you go one-day sightseeing, (富士山か東京と横浜を観光する) Go sightseeing for Mt.Fuji or Tokyo and Yokohama. It depends on how you define sightseeing, what transportation you use and where you stay. If you use a bullet train and just taking a photo of Mt.Fuji, it is possible to go sightseeing Mt.Fuji and Yokohama within a day.  If you do not use super- express train like a bullet train, go sightseeing for Yokohama and Tokyo within a day is more realistic.

Comment: @user3856370 Thanks for correcting. Since I saw more a can of "tuna with cheese sauce" than "beef with cheese sauce", I was confused.

Comment: Your welcome. I can't imagine **any** combination of these ingredients that would make a nice sandwich.

Comment: @user3856370 If you are a vegan, it is not the case though, I would add fried eggs and tomatoes for nice sandwiches.

Comment: So it's context dependent?  I'm going to assume from the wording of this answer that I am grammatically allowed to use both か and と to connect a string of nouns.

Comment: @SuperWild1 Yes, it's context dependent. Say, you go one-day sightseeing.  (富士山か東京と横浜を観光する) Go sightseeing for Mt.Fuji or Tokyo and Yokohama. It depends on how you define sightseeing, what transportation you use and where you stay. If you use a bullet train and just taking a photo of Mt.Fuji, it is possible to go sightseeing Mt.Fuji and Yokohama within a day.  If you do not use super express train like a bullet train, go sightseeing for Yokohama and Tokyo within a day is more realistic.